# What are the best practises to prepare for AWS Certified Solutions Architect - Associate 2017 pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I have been going in details about all the major services of AWS like **`EC2, S3, VPC, Volumes, EIP, Subnets, Gateways, Route53, Auto Scaling, ELB, RDS, DynamoDb, Redshift, Kinesis, Video Transcoder`** etc .
But going in details about each topic from the official documentation of AWS is tough and hard to remember.

> What are the patterns, guidelines, practise tests which I can follow
> to clear the topics throughly.
>
> Also do I need to purchase the Questions sets provided by many
> websites, or just go with the free available ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no replacement for experience. Sit at the AWS console and spend time practicing with all the major AWS services (the ones you listed). Then take the time to read the FAQs and White Papers. For added knowledge watch the AWS videos on YouTube. Amazon has good training videos on their training website. I also recommend A Cloud Guru for training videos. Another good resource is QwikLabs.

It is possible to memorize enough to pass the exam by taking practice tests, but then your certification will be worthless to an employer. If your goal is a job, then take the time to really understand how the AWS cloud works and the services offered.

I have seven AWS certifications so I do have a real solid understanding of AWS and their exams. I also have more than 10 years actually working with AWS as part of my job.

[Update]

Time and again I see people put emphasis on taking practice tests. Don't do it. Take a practice test when you know what you are ready to take the exam. I recommend taking all the QwikLabs AWS labs. Do all of them (sometimes several times) and the above suggestions and you won't need a practice test. You will fly thru the exam.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed review and also making emphasis on practising with console in a must one. I have taken Udemy course as well. Now need to roll into console for greater details and clarity

Comment: as you are well versed with AWS. Can you brief a little about the exam patterns and question types which comes in Associate Level of the exam.
Are the topics covered in depth and detailed?

Comment: After you take an exam, you under NDA. So, in general, the associate level questions are generally one or two lines long with multiple choice questions. AWS does mix this up a bit with longer questions. I would not worry about the exam. I would review the Exam Guide and make sure that you know everything listed. Once you do take the test.

Comment: Thanks @John I will keep that noted.

Answer (score 4):

[RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM): The [AWS Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/)

The majority of AWS services revolve around **Amazon EC2** and **Amazon S3**. Therefore, you would gain a lot by actually reading the manuals for these services:

- [Amazon S3 Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/)
- [Amazon EC2 User Guide for Linux Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/)
  or
  [Amazon EC2 User Guide for Windows Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/)

Yes, they are big. You don't have to read every word. Instead, download the PDF and look through the entire guide. Read the headings. Look at the pictures. Read the sections that grab your attention.

You'll actually learn quite a lot!

The other services are also important, but if you don't have the time do learn it all, at least read the FAQs, eg:

- [Amazon VPC FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/)
- [Amazon RDS FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/)
- [Amazon Redshift FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/faqs/)

Most important, however, is having **actual experience** using the services. The exams want to test your actual knowledge of AWS services, not how much you've crammed for the exam.

Comment: The manuals describe about the services in key points which are very important ones. Thanks for pointing the same.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for preparing for AWS is to go through the FAQS of each topic mentioned in the official documentation.
Apart from official documentation you need to opt for some practise questions. You can try Whizlabs, Udemy , A Cloud Guru etc.
And for your final revision point to get through the topics in brief you can go for

```
http://jayendrapatil.com.
```

All the topics are covered with detailed explanations.

Comment: this website https://techcloudonline.com  have a lot of practice question for free --disclaimer I have created it

Answer (score 0):

*Preparing for AWS Solutions Architect will require you to plan before you start ahead the process.*

> First and foremost get the details of each topic like EC2, VPC, S3,
>   ELB from their official documentation and also videos available for
>   them as well. The details are mentioned in the [*[Whitepapers of AWS][1](https://www.aws.training/certification?src=arc-assoc)*](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/) for
>   CSAA exam.

After getting the details about the topic you need to go through the Practice tests from many sources available. 
Please purchase the question sets rather than going through the free ones available as there's some conflicts in answers in the free version of the question sets.

> When you are done the above process, now yo can purchase the official
>   Paper Sample from AWS.

**Note:** Please go through the Best Practices of each services in the current practical situations according to the requirement.
You will get more clarity of the overall services of AWS in terms of cost, availability, latency to make the infra and application durable and available.